# How can I install a specific version of npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I want to install a specific version of npm (1.3.11). How can I do this? Is this even possible?

The [npm docs](https://npmjs.org/doc/faq.html) explain how to install the latest version, but not a specific version.

Answer (score 3):

You can suffix any NPM package with a specific version, including `npm` itself:

```
npm install npm@1.3.11 [-g]
```

(if you use `-g`, you will overwrite your currently installed version, which may or may not be  your intention so be careful)